# Installing wordpress on xampp gives empty tables only

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I’m installing wordpress on xampp and i have problem. installation is not completed properly and all database tables are empty (wp_postmeta). Not sure how it manages to create tables but not enter data. after last step of wordpress install, page is not loaded completely, it doesn’t say “WP installed and you can now login". ok i can login but control panel it not exist . I tried creating new user for database with all privileges and using these details for installation. Still doesn’t work. some table still empty like (wp_postmeta, wp_commentmeta, wp_comments, wp_links, wp_posts, wp_termmeta, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships and wp_term_taxonomy) , something is preventing entering sample data and I’m not sure what this could be. xampp server is working ok! (apache and mysql run and work).

Comment: unfinished or corrupted install. SUPPOSED (IF AND ONLY IF), this is a fresh install, drop all tables in the database, and run the installer again

Comment: i think it corrupted  install and i  drop all tables in the database, and run the installer still same problem

Comment: i am thinking an issue with SQL collation (try setting new database with collation of `utf8_general_ci`). Can you post the php error log generated? `XAMPP_DIR\apache\logs\error.log`, XAMPP_DIR being where you xampp was installed

Comment: i just want to see if there's an error made in the PHP side as the cause of crash mate